# ForLoop in Python - iterator should augment by a multiplier factor of 100

Tags: python, for-loop, iterator

I'm just trying to figure out how something like this (written in C) :

```
for (long long i = 100; i <= pow(10,length); i = i * 100){}
```

would be translated into Python 3.
As the last part, where the iterator should multiply itself by 100, is the point where I got stuck.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your current attempt?

Comment: Well, `for` loops are essentially `while` loops...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a `while` loop instead:

```
i = 100
while i <= 10 ** length:
    # ....
    i *= 100
```

or use a generator function:

```
def powerranger(start, end, mult):
    val = start
    while val <= end:
        yield val
        val *= mult
```

and

```
for i in powerranger(100, 10 ** length, 100):
    # ...
```

Comment: Just for that name :)

Comment: Generators FTW!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a for loop, this C-type loop would be better translated using a `while` loop:

```
i = 100
while i <= pow(10, length):
    # Use the value of `i` here.
    i *= 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Import lots of things:

```
from itertools import takewhile, count

for i in (100 ** x for x in takewhile(lambda y: y <= length // 2, count(1))):
    # do something useful here
```

Answer (score -1):

```
j = 100
for i in range(length):
    j *= 100
    print j # or other use of j
```

Not too pythonic but it works.

Comment: I is multiplied by `10**2`, and the condition is `<=` in the original question, so you probably want something more like `range(length//2 + 1)`